# Nginx stops responding after few seconds

Tags: nginx, debian

Debian 7.8, nginx 1.8.0

Reboot my server, call a page, got the page, access logs are correct.

```
5.49.32.xxx - - [06/Aug/2015:14:22:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"
5.49.32.xxx - - [06/Aug/2015:14:22:31 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "http://f1.mydomain.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36"
```

And after about 1 min of server up, nginx stops responding.
Nothing in access_log, nothing in error_log.

`service nginx restart` doesn't solve the problem. If I want to get a response, the only way is to reboot my server.

I checked my syslog and kern.log, I saw nothing interesting.

No idea where the problem could be...

Here is my conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name
        f1.mydomain.fr
    ;

    root /var/www/mydomain/current/web;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain-error.log error;

    location / {
        # For Symfony2
         try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config|app_test|clear|ocp|apcu)\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/conf/fastcgi;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: We've got the same problem as you: no data. Try changing to`error_log /var/…/mydomain-error.log debug;` and see if you get something that helps pin down more information.

Comment: Style nothing in logs after few seconds of up, no weird errors just before

Comment: Bouffe or @msw, were you able to get this to work?  I'm having the same problem where nginx w/ php-fdm works fine for about 5 minutes.  I've also noticed that if I make requests from two different browsers from the same external client, it seizes even sooner.  However, mine does continue to serve pages w/ php on localhost after external requests cease to respond.  Like you, no errors in access_log or error_log.  May I ask how/if you were able to resolve the problem?

Comment: We migrate to AWS since, but I was never able to get this works.
I've created a neww server from scratch...